# Why should I use ogg and webm file?

Tags: mediaelement.js, webm, vorbis

There is a option to add ogg and webm file in wordpress plugin of MediaElement.js. Why I should use it? What is the benefit?

Comment: Where did you find this option to play ogg files in MediaElement.js?

Answer (score 3):

[Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) is a free **media container** format by Xiph.Org. It is typically used to hold audio compressed with Vorbis, but can also be used for FLAC audio and Theora video.

[Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) is an efficient, royalty-free **audio compression** format. It is open source and is supported on many platforms (such as Windows, Linux, smartphones). It has better audio quality than MP3, and comparable quality to AAC.

[WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) is a free **media container** format, whose development is sponsored by Google, that is a subset of the existing free format Matroska.

WebM files typically contain video compressed with VP8 or VP9, and audio compressed with Vorbis or Opus. The VP8 video codec is somewhat less efficient than H.264 / MPEG-4 AVC, but its royalty-free status means that it may supported on more platforms than MP4 video files.

Comment: Strictly speaking, WebM is not a codec. It's a container (based on Matroska), hosting video/audio streams. And it's quite common that WebM contains the very same Vorbis-encoded audio.

Comment: Thank you! I now reread this post of mine from many years ago, and edited the text content to be better.

Answer (score 0):

Browser compatibility, sound/video quality, and bandwidth or download time.

Mozilla has the [authoritative answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) on browser compatibility. tl;dr `mp3` has the widest browser support, `webm` is supported by almost everyone, except Safari.

For sound quality, `webm` and `ogg` should be better than `mp3`.

For bandwidth or download time, I don't see much difference between the three formats. Obviously, picking `mp3` enables one file download that works in all browsers, so should be the least bandwidth.

All things considered, I have my audio source arrays set for `webm` as the first element and `mp3` as the second element. I considered doing `webm`, `ogg`, and `mp3` but this seems like overkill.

Comment: "For sound quality, webm and ogg should be better than mp3", the first two are containers that could contain different audio formats.  So this is a non-sensical comparison.  Granted the third (mp3) could contain different audio formats too.  So it's not entierly straightforward.